# couldn't find method readString(Path) while loading BulkApi

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I'm going to load the bulk of data using BulkApi but while compiling the code it shows me the error.

```
 private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BulkApiService.class);

    @Autowired
    public ElasticSearchConfig elasticSearchConfig;
    private static String FOLDER_PATH = "src/main/resources/allFiles";

    public void loadAllDataUsingBulkApi() {
        Client client = elasticSearchConfig.client();
        AtomicReference<BulkRequestBuilder> request = new AtomicReference<>(client.prepareBulk());
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        try (Stream<Path> filePathStream = Files.walk(Paths.get(FOLDER_PATH))) {
            filePathStream.forEach(filePath -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                    counter.getAndIncrement();
                    try {
                        String content = Files.readString(filePath);
                        JSONObject contentJson = new JSONObject(content);
                        HashMap contentMap = new Gson().fromJson(contentJson.toString(), HashMap.class);
                        request.get().add(client.prepareIndex("indexName", "default").setSource(contentMap));

                    } catch (IOException ignore) {
                        log.error(ignore.toString());
                    }

                }
            });
            BulkResponse bulkResponse = request.get().execute().actionGet();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

> Expected Output : it should load all the data on specified path to ES.
>   Actual output :
>
> Error on "String content = Files.readString(filePath);" that couldn't find symbol.
>     symbol:   method readString(Path)
>     location: class Files

Comment: Your java version is probably not the latest JDK/JRE 11. The readString() method is only available from 11 and onward.

Comment: Sir i am working with **JAVA 11**. Please also suggest me its compatible method for JAVA 8 as my all of code except this in **JAVA8** . For only **BulkApi class** I need to use **JAVA11** but it still not works fine for me.

Comment: There isn't one! You just need to read the File to a String, right? There are many examples on how to do that on the web.